# How to use PyCall in Julia to convert Python output to Julia DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, julia, quandl

I would like to retrieve some data from `quandl` and analyse them in Julia. There is, unfortunately, no official API available for this (yet). I am aware of [this solution](https://github.com/lissonc/Quandl.jl), but it is still quite limited in functionality and doesn't follow the same syntax as the original Python API.

I thought it would be a smart thing to use `PyCall` to retrieve the data using the official Python API from within Julia. This does yield an output, but I'm not sure how I can convert it to a format that I would be able to use within Julia (ideally a `DataFrame`).

I have tried the following.

```
using PyCall, DataFrames
@pyimport quandl

data = quandl.get("WIKI/AAPL", returns = "pandas");
```

Julia converts this output to a `Dict{Any,Any}`. When using `returns = "numpy"` instead of `returns = "pandas"`, I end up with a `PyObject rec.array`.

How can I get `data` to be a Julia `DataFrame` as `quandl.jl` would return it? Note that `quandl.jl` is not an option for me because it doesn't support automatic retrieval of multiple assets and lacks several other features, so it's essential that I can use the Python API.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into a difference in Python/Pandas versions. I happen to have two configurations easily available to me; Pandas 0.18.0 in Python 2 and Pandas 0.19.1 in Python 3. The answer [@niczky12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044587/niczky12) provided works well in the first configuration, but I'm seeing your `Dict{Any,Any}` behavior in the second configuration.  Basically, something changes between those two configurations such that PyCall detects a mapping-like interface for Pandas objects and then exposes that interface as a dictionary through an automatic conversion.  There are two options here:

1. Work with the dictionary interface:

   ```
   data = quandl.get("WIKI/AAPL", returns = "pandas")
   cols = keys(data)
   df = DataFrame(Any[collect(values(data[c])) for c in cols], map(Symbol, cols))
   ```
2. Explicitly disable the auto-conversion and use the PyCall interface to extract the columns as [niczky12 demonstrated in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42621302/176071). Note that `data[:Open]` will do auto-conversion to a mapped dictionary and `data["Open"]` will just return a `PyObject`.

   ```
   data = pycall(quandl.get, PyObject, "WIKI/AAPL", returns = "pandas")
   cols = data[:columns]
   df = DataFrame(Any[Array(data[c]) for c in cols], map(Symbol, cols))
   ```

In both cases, though, note that the all-important date index isn't included in the resulting data frame.  You almost certainly want to add that as a column:

```
df[:Date] = collect(data[:index])
```

Comment: There's actually a third option — disable auto-conversion and then wrap the `PyObject` with the Pandas.jl library. That doesn't get you into the JuliaStats ecosystem, but it simplifies using Pandas analysis functions from within Julia.

Comment: Good spot! I had a feeling this issue was due to Python2 vs Python3. Also, I agree the data index should be included.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option:

First, extract the column names from you `data` object:

```
julia> colnames = map(Symbol, data[:columns]);
12-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :Open                
 :High                
 :Low                 
 :Close               
 :Volume              
 Symbol("Ex-Dividend")
 Symbol("Split Ratio")
 Symbol("Adj. Open")  
 Symbol("Adj. High")  
 Symbol("Adj. Low")   
 Symbol("Adj. Close") 
 Symbol("Adj. Volume")
```

Then pour all your columns into an DataFrame:

```
julia> y = DataFrame(Any[Array(data[c]) for c in colnames], colnames)

6×12 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ Open  │ High  │ Low   │ Close │ Volume   │ Ex-Dividend │ Split Ratio │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ 28.75 │ 28.87 │ 28.75 │ 28.75 │ 2.0939e6 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │
│ 2   │ 27.38 │ 27.38 │ 27.25 │ 27.25 │ 785200.0 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │
│ 3   │ 25.37 │ 25.37 │ 25.25 │ 25.25 │ 472000.0 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │
│ 4   │ 25.87 │ 26.0  │ 25.87 │ 25.87 │ 385900.0 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │
│ 5   │ 26.63 │ 26.75 │ 26.63 │ 26.63 │ 327900.0 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │
│ 6   │ 28.25 │ 28.38 │ 28.25 │ 28.25 │ 217100.0 │ 0.0         │ 1.0         │

│ Row │ Adj. Open │ Adj. High │ Adj. Low │ Adj. Close │ Adj. Volume │
├─────┼───────────┼───────────┼──────────┼────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.428364  │ 0.430152  │ 0.428364 │ 0.428364   │ 1.17258e8   │
│ 2   │ 0.407952  │ 0.407952  │ 0.406015 │ 0.406015   │ 4.39712e7   │
│ 3   │ 0.378004  │ 0.378004  │ 0.376216 │ 0.376216   │ 2.6432e7    │
│ 4   │ 0.385453  │ 0.38739   │ 0.385453 │ 0.385453   │ 2.16104e7   │
│ 5   │ 0.396777  │ 0.398565  │ 0.396777 │ 0.396777   │ 1.83624e7   │
│ 6   │ 0.420914  │ 0.422851  │ 0.420914 │ 0.420914   │ 1.21576e7   │
```

Thanks to @Matt B. for the suggestions to simplify the code.

The problem with the above is that the column types are `Any` inside the dataframe. To make it a bit more efficient here are a few functions which get the job done:

```
# first, guess the Julia equivalent of type of the object
function guess_type(x::PyCall.PyObject)
  string_dtype = x[:dtype][:name]
  julia_string = string(uppercase(string_dtype[1]), string_dtype[2:end])

  return eval(parse("$julia_string"))
end

# convert an individual column, falling back to Any array if the guess was wrong
function convert_column(x)
  y = try Array{guess_type(x)}(x) catch Array(x) end
  return y
end

# put everything together into a single function
function convert_pandas(df)
  colnames =  map(Symbol, data[:columns])
  y = DataFrame(Any[convert_column(df[c]) for c in colnames], colnames)

  return y
end
```

The above, when applied to your `data` gives the same column names as before, but with correct `Float64` column types:

```
y = convert_pandas(data);
showcols(y)
9147×12 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name        │ Eltype  │ Missing │
├───────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1     │ Open        │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 2     │ High        │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 3     │ Low         │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 4     │ Close       │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 5     │ Volume      │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 6     │ Ex-Dividend │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 7     │ Split Ratio │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 8     │ Adj. Open   │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 9     │ Adj. High   │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 10    │ Adj. Low    │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 11    │ Adj. Close  │ Float64 │ 0       │
│ 12    │ Adj. Volume │ Float64 │ 0       │
```

Comment: It seems you cannot index into a `Dict{Any}{Any}` object using Symbols. I tried using Strings instead; I think this may have changed in a recent version but should work once I figure out the type conversion. `Array(data[colname])` returns `MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type Dict{Any}{Any} to an object of type Array{T}{N}`. I'm on version 0.5.0.

Comment: I did convert the column names to symbols, using `colnames = map(x -> Symbol(String(x)), data[:columns][:values])` Have you done that too? It works fine on my machine, and I'm using 0.5 as well.

Comment: What versions of PyCall and DataFrames are you using?  This should work just fine.  It can be slightly simpler and add column names with: `cols = map(Symbol, data[:columns]); DataFrame(Any[Array(data[c]) for c in cols], cols)`

Comment: @Constantin I edited the answer using the above suggestions and added functions to make the conversion simpler.

Comment: `map(Symbol, data[:columns])` returns `EEROR: KeyError: key :columns not found`. I tried `map(Symbol, keys(data))` which returns a `Symbol` array, which I cannot use to index into the `Dict`. I tried `colnames = keys(data)` to index into the `Dict` using strings rather than symbols, but this again gives me the above `MethodError`. I'm very confused by why this would work on your machine and not mine. Did you load any extra packages?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API. Just use Quandl.jl: https://github.com/milktrader/Quandl.jl

```
using Quandl
data = quandlget("WIKI/AAPL")
```

This has the added advantage of getting the data in a useful Julia format (a TimeArray), which has appropriate methods defined for working with such data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this option (see my question), but this is an unofficial API and it's functionality is very limited. For example, I have not managed to selectively retrieve multiple series and have them returned in a date-matched DataFrame object. The official Python API supports this, so I would like to build a wrapper for it instead of using the unofficial API.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was what you linked to. OK then, I hope you can use the competent advice you got by the other answers, then.